# add-apt-repository times out

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, unix

I have a shell script that initializes our machines, it has the following code in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function retry {
  local n=1
  local max=5
  local delay=5
  while true; do
    "$@" && break || {
      if [[ $n -lt $max ]]; then
        ((n++))
        echo "Command failed. Attempt $n/$max:"
        sleep $delay;
      else
        fail "The command has failed after $n attempts."
      fi
    }
  done
}

set -e

...
retry timeout 20 add-apt-repository \
  "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) \
  stable"
```

The problem is, every time I try to run this script using sudo ./init.sh, it gets to the retry line and looks as if the command of add-apt-repository timed out since I am getting the message from the rety function: "Command failed. Attempt..." .

When I try to run the add-apt-repository command manually outside of the script it does work (just sudo add-apt-repository etc.)

Comment: Did you run `timeout 20 add-apt-repository ...` manually? Maybe run `sudo bash -x ./init.sh` or add a line `set -x` to your script to see what gets executed.

Comment: Did `add-apt-repository` itself give any error messages ?

Comment: Nope, add-apt-repository worked fine